# enum data type for liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquid-layout

I'm currently working on a liquibase.xml file to create table table_a. One of my fields is `<column name="state" type="ENUM('yes','no')">`
I'm using postgresql as my DBMS. is there anything like enum data type? 
I've read in this like http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Enum

that postgresql doesn't have such data type. CREATE TYPE function is used to create this data type. I still don't know how to make it in liquibase though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well of course PostgreSQL has an enum type (which is clearly documented in the link you have shown and the manual).

I don't think Liquibase "natively" supports enums for PostgreSQL, but you should be able to achieve it with a custom SQL:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="Arthur">
  <sql>CREATE TYPE my_state AS ENUM ('yes','no')</sql>
  <table name="foo">
    <column name="state" type="my_state"/>
  </table>
</changeSet>
```

For a simple yes/no column, I'd actually use the `boolean` type instead of an enum

Comment: This seems to suggest otherwise: https://gist.github.com/wilmoore/812253#file-modify-column-xml

Comment: Also it's good practice to provide a rollback command when doing custom sql in liquibase. http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html

Comment: @1in9ui5t it doesn't work!!! There's no "enum" type on Liquibase docs (https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-column.html#Informa).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to creating a new type would be a simple CHECK constraint on a `varchar(3)` column:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="X">
    <table name="t">
        <column name="c" type="varchar(3)"/>
    </table>
    <sql>ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT check_yes_no CHECK (c = 'yes' OR c = 'no')</sql>
</changeSet>
```

That might play better with the client side, or not. I think `boolean` (as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name) would be a better call for this specific case: saying exactly what you mean usually works out better than the alternatives.

Comment: I agree: a check constraint is probably even better than an ENUM

Comment: You can use "checkConstraint" according to Liquibase docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315020/postgresql-check-constraint-in-liquibase