# PostgreSQL Check Constraint in Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am wanting to create a check constraint in Liquibase on a PostgreSQL database table for an integer data type column that follows this logic:

```
int_value >= 0 AND int_value <= 6
```

What is the proper XML request to make this happen?

Comment: You need to write the  appropriate `alter table` in a `<sql>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction @a_horse_with_no_name. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 19):

This should be the way:

```
     <column name="int_value" type="INT" >
        <constraints checkConstraint="CHECK (int_value &gt;= 0 AND int_value &lt;= 6)"/>
    </column>
```

However, current Liquibase (3.5.1) ignores `checkConstraint` attribute. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/374/files), but it is added only to 4.0 milestone.

Thus, we have to use the raw sql for check constraints for the time being. This works for me:

```
<createTable tableName="test">
     <column name="int_value" type="INT"/>
</createTable>
<sql>
    ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT int_check CHECK (int_value &gt;=0 AND int_value &lt;= 6)
</sql>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "checkConstraint" attribute still not working. I'm using liquibase version 4.4.3.

Comment: **UPDATE**Still not working in 2023 despite being clearly dictated in the docs that it does. The [PR mentioned](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/374/files) is now closed unmerged . *using Liquibase with Spring Boot Kotlin `"org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.17.2`

Comment: @HackerMan0 Yes exactly the documentation is misleading. Overall Liquibase is unstable and dangerous, in my opinion it is NOT production-ready.

Answer (score 2):

```
<sql endDelimiter="\nGO">
  ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT check_name CHECK (int_value &gt;=0 AND int_value &lt;= 6)
</sql>
```

Comment: No need for the `\nGO` delimiter. In this case I would use `splitStatements="false"` as you have only a single statement anyway

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase currently supports `addCheckConstraint` but the feature seems to be reserved for PRO licenses:
`Change Type 'pro:addCheckConstraint' is not allowed without a valid Liquibase Pro License.`

`createTable:columns:column:constraints:checkConstraint` does nothing for me and also doesn't produce the license message.

I wasn't aware that Liquibase had a licensed version before this. The workaround is accomplishing this with SQL as stated in other answers.

[Liquibase PRO Change Types](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/pro/home.html)