# Adding 'CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (po_document IS JSON))' in liquibase

Tags: liquibase, oracle12c

I want to add check constraint to BLOB type column which stores JSON data, in CREATE Table script in liquibase(version 3.3.5, database -Oracle 12C). but it does not compile. Can anyone please explain what is the right syntax to add constraint which ensures only JSON type data would be inserted. I followed this question
Plain sql : `CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (po_document IS JSON))`
But not sure what is liquibase equivalent for this.
[PostgreSQL Check Constraint in Liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315020/postgresql-check-constraint-in-liquibase)

```
<changeSet id="Change_id" author="xqz">
        <createTable tableName="table_name">
            <column name="pkey" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="table2_pkey" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(100)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="filters" type="BLOB">
                <constraints checkConstraint="ensure_json CHECK (filters IS JSON)" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

If I add constraint to filters column, build fails, If I remove it, build is successful. What am I doing wrong. I could not find syntax for it in liquibase docs.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define check constraints in liquibase, for aditional information see [this forum entry](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/how-to-define-a-check-constraint).

You'll have to use an `<sql>` tag like

```
<sql dbms=oracle>
   CREATE TABLE table_name (
      pkey integer PRIMARY KEY,
      table2_pkey integer NOT NULL,
      name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      flter blob CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (filters IS JSON)
   )
</sql>
```

Should work just the same, except that you have to add your own `<rollback>` tag.