# How do I define a check constraint on a column using liquibase?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, constraints, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase to build a Postgres SQL table. I have a column I'd like to add a check constraint to in order to ensure that the values in this column are in my set of acceptable values. [I've found some documentation on how to do an addCheckConstraint](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-check-constraint.html) but this seems to be for adding a check constraint to an already existing column. I don't need to do that, I have not yet created this table and would like to just include in the same changeset that is creating the table.

In my XML this is what I've got, autocomplete got me here so I know the  tag should be valid, but I'm unsure what to actually put in it.

```
<column name="size" type="varchar">
    <constraints checkConstraint="what goes here?"
</column>
```

The "size" column can only contain the values "small", "medium", or "large". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to put that into a `<sql>` tag.

Comment: looks like it's your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5133540

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so this is not what the <constraint> tag is for? I get that I can do it with a SQL statement, just preferred to use Liquibase's built-in tags for as much as possible if available. Felt like the <constraint> tag with a `checkConstraint` value was exactly what I needed, just didn't know the syntax of what goes in the `checkConstraint` field

Comment: @RostyslavBarmakov same deal here, this is using the <sql> tag, which I'm aware I can do, just preferred to do it with built-in liquibase tags if available. And it seemed the <constraint> tag was exactly what I needed. But I guess not

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-check-constraint.html) `<checkConstraint>` is only available in the pro (=paid) version. If you have a valid license key, you _can_ use it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is <addCheckConstraint> for adding a check constraint to an existing column, which is different from the column sub-tag of <checkConstraint> that goes in the definition of the column when you create it . It is listed under the sub-tags [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/column.html). But maybe it is still a pro feature?